# Using AbstractTransactionalJunit4SpringContextTests in Junit5

Tags: spring, junit, migrating

Is it possible to use AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests in junit5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Junit4 is the minimum version required. Note that `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` is just a convenience that delegates the `@Transactional` hooks to `JdbcTestUtils`.